# How to add a custom post deployment script to azure websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, kudu

My problem is that I need to run a custom cmd file after the build.
Instead of modifying the deployment scripts I just want to run few MSDOS commands to my deployment easily.

The task I need to do is to run a cmd at the repository located at /source/copyextrafiles.cmd after the build succeeded.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the azure portal on the CONFIGURE tab of your website add a "app settings" entry called POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION with the value of source/copyextrafiles.cmd
Save and the next deploy will run the cmd for you after the deploy.

Here the picture:
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! I use it to invoke gulp to build my static assets after my Python site has been deployed. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Where do I add the cmd file? I am hosting a .Net application with sturcture like D:\home\site\wwwroot

Comment: that path will be relative to the root of the source it's not relative to the wwwroot

Comment: This has been slightly updated since the answer: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks
The app setting is  called `SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH` and the value is a folder, where all bat/cmd/ps1 scripts will be executed.

Comment: @AdamSzabo What if I want to run one specific ps or exe file located in wwwroot\bin directory? Or how to automatically deploy such scripts to site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions directory?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative in addition to the solutions already provided is to copy the script in to a specific folder provided for [post deployment action hooks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks).

So after creating a new directory in "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\" named "PostDeploymentActions", you could just add script files (.bat, .cmd or .ps1) into the directory and they will all run, one by one, after each deployment.

Comment: That path will not be on the git repository for example.