# Run acceptance/smoke tests after deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have set up continuous deployment from a Visual Studio Online Git repository to an Azure Web App.

What is the best way to run acceptance/smoke tests on the website after a build is triggered and deployment has completed?

I have already tried `POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION` ([How to add a custom post deployment script to azure websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350201/how-to-add-a-custom-post-deployment-script-to-azure-websites)), but this seems to get ignored.

I also had a look at the Kudu PostDeployment hook (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks), which appears overly hacky.

I am deploying a standard ASP.NET 4 MVC site by the way. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was customizing the build process to add a RunScriptTask at the end, which invokes my tests.

You can pass build parameters to the RunScriptTask like so:

```
"-username user@example.org -password test123 -environment " + DeploymentSettings.GetValue(Of String)("ProviderHostedDeploymentEnvironmentName")
```

If you edit the build definition from Visual Studio -> Team Explorer -> Builds, there is a tab on the left called Process that breaks down the build steps. If you click *Show details* at the top, there is an option to download the XAML build process template. You can customize this as you wish and then create a new build process template from that file. (Note that XAML build process template file must be pushed to the remote repository beforehand)

Comment: I find it amusing that you find the Kudu PostDeployment hook "hacky" but the above isn't :-)

Comment: In fact Microsoft have just added a new [build preview](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/visual-studio-online-build-system-preview/) section to Visual Studio Online - you can configure the build steps using a friendly UI in much the same way as something like TeamCity. So executing a script post-deployment is even easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

What is hacky about the PostDeployment hook?

An alternative to that could be to subscribe to the PostDeployment hook from the Kudu/SCM site

```
POST /api/hooks
{
  "url": "http://www.callback.com/callback",
  "event": "PostDeployment",
  "insecure_ssl": false (set to true to ignore https certificate check, for test purposes only)
}
```

That would give you a POST like below on the specified URL when deployment is done:

```
{
  "id": "cd5bee7181e74ea38a3522e73253f6ebb8ed72fb",
  "status": "success", (could be pending, building, deploying, failed, success)
  "author_email": "someone@somewhere.com",
  "author": "Some One",
  "message": "My fix",
  "deployer": "Some One",
  "start_time": "2013-06-06T01:24:16.5873293Z",
  "end_time": "2013-06-06T01:24:17.63342Z"
}
```

[More info here on kudu github wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-hooks)