# Run "npm install" as a post deployment script on Azure

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular 4 on .NET Core MVC project hosted on Azure.  After each publish I would like to run NPM INSTALL to update all my dependencies.  Currently, I am opening Kudu and running it manually.  Not a big deal, but I was wondering if there a way to automate this.

Thank you.

EDIT:  The link posted below does clear part of my question, but I am still not sure how to create the .cmd file mentioned there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom post deployment script to azure websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350201/how-to-add-a-custom-post-deployment-script-to-azure-websites)

Comment: Thank you for the link @joncloud.  Although, there was no need to down vote my question.  Do you think, I would have wasted mine and everyone else's time to write a question if I have come across this link during my search.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more detailed explanation on how to achieve this:

1. Open Kudu by visiting https://your-app-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/
2. In the debug console, navigate to **site\deployments\tools**
3. If it does not exist, create a folder called PostDeploymentActions
4. In it create a file post-deploy.cmd (you can name it whatever you want)
5. In this file enter the following:

```js
cd "D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot"
call npm install
```

This assumes that package.json and node_modules are in your wwwroot directory.  If not enter the correct path.

After the deploy your cmd file will get executed.  To confirm, navigate to **home\LogFiles\SiteExtensions\MSDeploy** and view appManager.xml.  You should be able to see your cmd file executed there.

Hope this saves someone some research time.